# Gravatar/Identicon is not copied to all public communities

Tags: bug

is this intended or a bug?

On my Stack Overflow account, I set my data, and then click `Save and copy changes to all public communities`. This works for all data I entered, but not for the setting to use the Identicon or Gravatar.

It is set to use Gravatar on Stack Overflow but is still set to Identicon on Server Fault, other thins like my name are saved correctly on both.

Screenshots of [Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nnu5.png) and [Server Fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMksL.png)